# subtracting two values of unknown bitsize

Tags: c++, math, subtraction, twos-complement

I'm trying to subtract two values from each other using twos compliment. I have a problem with the overflowing bit. Since my container hold an unlimited bit sized integer, I don't know if the top bit of the result is really from the result or just the overflow. How would I get rid of the overflow without using `-` (I can't just do `1 << bits - 1` since that would involve using the container, which has no working `operator-` yet)

`0b1111011111 - 0b111010000 -> 0b1111011111 + 0b000110000 -> 1000001111`

vs (normally)

`0b00000101 - 0b000000001 -> 0b00000101 + 0b11111111 -> 0b100000100 -> 0b00000100`

Comment: Do you have a misprint? I think your `1000001111` should be `10000001111`. The misprinted `1000001111` happens to be the correct answer to the problem, arrived at in the wrong way; perhaps this has added to your confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calculate a - b you must somehow "arrange" the word - as you have to make for the 2 compliment a negation with the bitwidth of m=max(bitwidth(a), bitwidth(b)).

To get rid of the of overflow you just do mask = negate(1 << m), and apply the mask with bitwise and.
(Or you could just check that bit and treat it accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are subtracting the 9-bit `111010000` from the 10-bit `1111011111`. The two's complement of `111010000` is `...11111000110000`, where the dots are trying to show that you have to pad to the left with as many `1` bits as you need. Here, you need 10 bits, so the two's complement of `111010000` is not `000110000` but `1000110000`.

So you want to calculate `1111011111 + 1000110000 = 11000001111`, which you just truncate to 10 bits to get the correct answer `1000001111`.